# My dateFormat is not working for Flatpickr in Mobile

Tags: datepicker, flatpickr

I am using Datepicker of [Flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) and I have set the date format and it is working fine in desktop but in mobile it is not working properly.

This is my code that I added in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( window ).load( function( $ ){
        var limitFlatPicker;
        var afterTwoDays;
        var afterEightDays;
        limitFlatPicker = limitFlatPicker || {};
        limitFlatPicker = {
            defaultSettings: {
                selector: '.flatpickr-input',
                minDate: true,
                maxDate: true,
            },
            settings: {},
            init: function( options ) {
                this.settings = jQuery.extend( this.defaultSettings, options );
                if ( this.settings.minDate || this.settings.maxDate ) {
                    this.waitForFlatpicker( this.callback );
                }
            },
            waitForFlatpicker: function( callback ) {
                if ( typeof window.flatpickr !== 'function' ) {
                    setTimeout( function() { limitFlatPicker.waitForFlatpicker( callback ) }, 100 );
                }
                callback();
            },
            modifyPicker: function( picker, settings ) {
                flatpickr( picker ).set( settings );
            },
            callback: function() {
                var self;
                self = limitFlatPicker;
                jQuery( self.settings.selector ).each( function() {
                    var picker;
                    picker = jQuery( this )[0],
                    pickerSettings = {};

                    if ( self.settings.minDate ) {
                        pickerSettings.minDate = self.settings.minDate;
                    }
                    if ( self.settings.maxDate ) {
                        pickerSettings['maxDate'] = self.settings.maxDate;
                    }
                    if ( self.settings.dateFormat ) {
                        pickerSettings.dateFormat = self.settings.dateFormat;
                    }
                    self.modifyPicker( picker, pickerSettings );
                } );
            }
        }

            limitFlatPicker.init({
               minDate: new Date(),
               selector: '#form-field-form_field_date',
               dateFormat: 'm-d-Y',
            });     
           
    } );
</script>

<?php
},11);
```

The `dateFormat: 'm-d-Y'` is working fine in desktop and in mobile, it is not showing this dateformat.

Any help is much appreciated.